# Clear input field after button click

Tags: javascript, html, button

How can I reset the input field, after clicking on the button?

```html
<div class="form-group autocomplete">
<div class="input-group search">
<input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn color-cta-3 search-button" onmousedown="getInput();alert('Danke fuer Ihre Eingabe Thank you'); return false;" >Eingabe</button></div></div>
<script>
function getInput(){
ET_Event.eventStart('TestCloud', document.getElementById('search').value, 'TestCloud')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value of the input = '';

*document.getElementById('search').value = '';*

```html
<div class="form-group autocomplete">
<div class="input-group search">
<input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn color-cta-3 search-button" onmousedown="getInput();alert('Danke fuer Ihre Eingabe Thank you'); return false;" >Eingabe</button></div></div>
<script>
function getInput(){
//ET_Event.eventStart('TestCloud', document.getElementById('search').value, 'TestCloud')
document.getElementById('search').value = '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, there is some unwanted code in yours.

```html
<div class="form-group autocomplete">
  <div class="input-group search">
    <input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn color-cta-3 search-button" onclick="getInput();">Eingabe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function getInput() {
    document.getElementById('search').value = '';
    alert('Danke fuer Ihre Eingabe Thank you');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example using jQuery to delete the content.

```js
$("#delete-button").click(()=>{
  $("#search").val("")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
<button id="delete-button">Delete</button>
```